# Tell Controller On Another Domain There Is New Data

Tags: php, javascript, json, controller, jsonp

Currently I have two sites hosted on different domains.

**SITE 1:** I want to use as a CMS for content creation only.
(writing,editing,etc.)

**SITE 2:** I want to use for viewing content.

Theoretically, what I'd like to be able to do, is create multiple peices of content in **SITE 1**.

When I'm ready to publish these I'll press a 'publish' button, which will alert **SITE 2** that there is new content and pass the values via JSONP.

**SITE 2** will then pull in the data via JSON and do what it wants...(enter into DB, etc.)

...so yeah I'm stuck at the theoretical part.  I'm not exactly sure where to go now but here's what I'm thinking.

There's a javascript function on **SITE 1** that is called when I choose publish:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: postData,
    url: 'http://site2.com/admin_json_controller.php',
    success: function(data) {
        // 'data' is a JSON object which we can access directly.
        // Evaluate the data.success member and do something appropriate...
        if (data.success == true){
            alert('worked!');
        }
        else{
            alert('did not work!');
        }
    }
});
```

This posts a json object to a php file on **SITE 2**.  This file will simply be waiting for this post object. When it recognizes the post object...it will then enter the values into the database.

Does this make sense?  I have a feeling I don't quite understand JSON yet but any help, questions, tips, pointers are much appreciated.

THANKS

Comment: Why use ajax? A plain old html form sounds suitable.

Comment: I'm working on a prototype to do something similar at the moment, but I was going to go with a recurring ajax call to a webservice to check for updated values in the database.  I think for your purposes you just need to submit the data to the database when you click the Publish button, but I'm very interested in knowing if anyone in the community has any input on bringing your concept to fruition.

Comment: If you want to syndicate content, you could publish an RSS feed from the first and use that on the second, using a query to find all the content that is "active" when building the feed. Otherwise, you could use a SOAP or XML-RPC setup to push the data to the second server and save into your database.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify things you have two options:

1. Use the same database for both domains.
2. Do a simple post to the other domain. Set the action of the form to script on the other domain. The other domain can access the variables via `$_POST`.

Comment: If the site hasn't been built yet, option 1 could be done fairly easily with [ExpressionEngine's Multi-Site Manager](http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/multiple_site_manager/).

Comment: Like your 2nd option there but I'd really like to pass off the data as JSON.  Is this possible via a simple html form?